# при подключении к базе данных C# MS Sql, выдаёт такую ошибку "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

при подключении к базе данных C# MS Sql, выдаёт такую ошибку... ест идеи с чем может бить связано?   код, не прикрепляю, потому что смысла нету, он большой, чисто по символам есть идеи?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `код, не прикрепляю, потому что смысла нету` - ну а нам нету смысла вам отвечать без кода, ибо вам прямым текстом написано в ошибке "Неправильный синтаксис", что означает у вас опечатка, не там запятая или точка, ну и так далее. А теперь подумайте, как мы без кода должны узнать где у вас там опечатка?

Comment: проверьте connectionstring к базе и что по кредам, которые указаны для данной строки, вы можете залогиниться через MS SQL Management Studia.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас проверю...

Comment: Нет такой БД - MS Sql. Эта СУБД называется Sql Server и никак иначе.

Comment: ок, понятно......

Comment: нашел решение, проблему, спасибо за ответы

Comment: `Login = '...' AND Password = '...'`

Comment: спасибо Евгений :) да проблема была именно в этом :)

Comment: Зачем вы запрашиваете из базы догин и пароль в запросе где они известны еще до того как этот запрос ушел в базу? Берите только id или вообще делайте count()

Comment: А еще в аду для тех, кто хранит пароли в базе в открытом виде, есть отдельный котёл. Используйте хэширование.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно исправить запрос - вместо ',' должен быть AND

```
...WHERE Login = '{login}' AND Password = '{password }'";
```